# How to return both stream and file length from WCF Restful json webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest, multipart

Hihi all,

I am able to return stream from my WCF restful json webservice, everything works fine. But when I mixed the stream with another piece of data (both wrap into a custom class), upon consuming the webservice from my client, it gives an error message of "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

Any advice how can I achieve the above? What it's required for my webservice is to allow downloading of a file with the file length as an additional piece of information for validation at the client end.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

There are various restrictions while using `Stream` in WCF service contracts - as per [this MDSN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751463.aspx), only one (output) parameter or return value (of type stream) can be used while streaming.

In another [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) (this is anyway a good resource, if you want to stream large data using WCF), it has been hinted that one can combine stream and some input/output data by using Message Contract. 
For example, see [this blog post](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2011/01/streaming-files-over-wcf.html) where author has used explicit message contract to upload both file name & file data. You have to do the similar thing from download perspective.

Finally, if nothing works then you can always push the file length as a custom (or standard such as content-length) HTTP header. If you are hosting in IIS then enable ASP.NET compatibility and use `HttpContext.Current.Response` to add your custom header.